# how to find Elements in Selenium By specific path tag ,and click on in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

if I have many path tag and I want to find specific tag like below example of code

```
< path d="a">
<path d="b">
<path d="c">
<path d="a">
```

how I can find  elements have < path d ="a" > and click on it in selenium

Comment: //path[@d='a'] Would be a simple xpath.

Comment: I try but not worked,, the path tag inside g and svg tag

Answer (score 2):

If the element is within `svg` tag, the syntax of the Xpath would be

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
Or
//*[name()='svg']
```

The required Xpath for the shared HTML might be

```
//*[local-name()='svg']//*[local-name()='g']//*[local-name()='path' and @d='a']
```

If the above xpath does not work, share more HTML code.

Links to refer:

[SVG element](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements)

[Find unique locators](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Comment: what's do you mean of local name()? it's should be local-name or it's like variable ?

Comment: Refer those links

Answer (score 1):

You can find the required path element using the below XPath.

```
//path[@d='a']
```

So for clicking the element you can use something like;

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//path[@d='a']").click()
```

Comment: I try this , but nor find, my path tag is inside g tag and g tag inside svg tag